# Where can I download a zip for requests?

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

'requests' is a python module to handle requests, which I cannot install via pip (i.e. `pip install requests`) because of a firewall issue. I require a zipped versioof 'requests' so I can install it via

```
pip install file.zip
```

But I cannot find a location of such a `zip` file...

Comment: why cant you download the readily available tarball and install it?

Comment: you have firewall issues, or proxy issues? If latter, add --proxy parameter with the correct http proxy. This works well at my office desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the `requests` tarball from [it's PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) and then install it:

```
$ pip install ~/Downloads/requests-2.9.1.tar.gz
```

You can also install it directly:

```
$ pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-2.9.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download a wheel or a tarball from PyPI:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#downloads